# need jquery validation for phone and country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam working on JQuery Validation..

Iam facing problems with Phone Validation and Iam not understanding how to add another validation as below:

**Here is what Iam achieving for:**

```
- telephone number in all UK formats (4 digit area code, a space, 7 digit local code), The 'telephone' number field (4 digit area code, a space, 7 digit local code)

- visitor location from a drop-down list which includes the items: South Yorkshire, Rest of England, Wales, Scotland, Northern Ireland, European Union, Rest of World, Other, and which includes an appropriate default,
```

please kindly check my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/B5sd8/18/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [Masked Input like this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?  Look at the Demos, and I am pretty sure you can format your mask to suit whatever phone number you need in the world.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in existing web services such as [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) that allow you to search for an address (or simply a country) for checking purpose.

I would highly recommend using [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) rather than re-inventing the wheel

a quick google search for uk numbers with jquery validate turned this up

[filters](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.validate.filters)

that looks like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function(phone_number, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
  phone_number.match(/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/);
  }, 'Please specify a valid phone number'
);
```

Comment: could you please tell me where to add this method??